# How to set the default video player?

Tags: settings, default-programs

How to set default video player 12.04 (and other default app's)
I try search system settings but can't find. (((

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set you default applications like that:

- Click on the shutdown button on the top right of you screen
- Go to "System Settings"
- Go to Details (2nd, last row)

[image]

- Go to "Default Applications"

[image]

Voilat! Here you can choose your default applications