# How do I set Guayadeque as the default music player?

Tags: default-programs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [File association to unlisted application](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82652/file-association-to-unlisted-application)
>   [How to set the default video player?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148956/how-to-set-the-default-video-player)

My choice of Music player is Guayadeque. It does not appear in my list of Properties/Open With/Show Other Applications.

I presume something needs editing, but can someone advise what?

The "Possible Duplicate" does not help here as that route currently only provides "Movie player" as the current selection, and no amount of clicking etc provides any method of selecting anything else.

At Least using the right click on an mp3 file followed by Properties/Open With/Show Other Applications gives a selection of programs to choose from, but Guayadeque is not there. Nor can I get to the file system to click on it directly (?). It does however show under the top level "Open With" but of course that does not set it as the default.

I am presuming that the list of players or the properties and categories of files is held in a system file somewhere which I can edit to either add Guayadeque to the Open With Defaults, or to change the properties of Guayadeque itself to show it is capable of playing music files and therefore show up in the list?

Comment: Or http://askubuntu.com/questions/68046/how-can-i-change-the-default-music-player or http://askubuntu.com/questions/156141/how-can-i-set-beatbox-as-default-music-player

Comment: answered here - http://askubuntu.com/questions/82652/file-association-to-unlisted-application/82657#82657 You need to edit `guayadeque.desktop` & add a %U to the `Exec= line` like - `Exec=guayadeque %U` for it to show in the properties context menu on supported mimetypes

Comment: @doug maybe post that as an answer and refer back to your initial answer?